# Identifier changes on multiple tabs

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of names with each name having an identification code on 3 tabs.

Example:

```
ID      First   Last          Comment
224589  Matt    Pfann
111111  Jame    Mondro
222222  Luck    Stevens
333333  Steve   White
444444  Tom     Brady
```

Tab 2 has the same list, but in different order.  Each name has the same identification code as tab 1.

Example:

```
ID      First   Last        Comment
222222  Luck    Stevens
333333  Steve   White
444444  Tom     Brady
111111  Jame    Mondro
224589  Matt    Pfann
```

I need help with a formula to use so that if I add a comment to a specific person on tab 1 (comprehensive list), the same comment would show up on tab 2 with that student.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with VLOOKUP().  See [this tutorial page](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions02.html) for more information.

Put this formula in Sheet2!D2 and fill down:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(F2,Sheet1!A$2:D$6,4,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(F2,Sheet1!A$2:D$6,4,FALSE))
```

This assumes your "comprehensive" data starts in A2 of Sheet1, and the second table starts in A2 of Sheet2.  Adjust the ranges as appropriate.  If your worksheets have names, you can replace "Sheet1" with the name of that worksheet (in quotes).

Using this formula, this data in Sheet 1:

[image]

...is transferred to Sheet 2 in the correct locations:

[image]

Comment: If you found this helpful you can [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).